# Why does my keyboard stop working sometimes in Chrome and Opera?

Tags: keyboard, browser

A persistent problem that I have had on my system for a while is that when I am browsing, in the one of the browsers I use, Chrome and Opera, the program stops responding to my keystrokes. I have to relaunch it before it works again. Do you know how I could fix this problem? Chrome is a much higher priority than Opera, because I prefer it much more.

Comment: Does it appear with any keystrokes? Or are there keys that still work? Or are the c , v keys not working for example?

Comment: None of the keys work

Comment: Special keyboard you are using?

Comment: Just the standard Chromebook keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubuntu, I had this problem due to a recent iBus  update.

By uninstalling the iBus  package the problem stopped. And nothing else bad has arisen.

Comment: I can't uninstall the package because synaptic says it will take a bunch of other things that I need with it, so I just disabled the iBus. (Sounds like something Apple would make)